# How do I delete my LinkedIn account?

Tags: linkedin, account-management

I haven't found any option to delete my LinkedIn account. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to:

1. Log in to your LinkedIn account
2. Select `Settings` from the arrow drop down in the top right

   [image: Settings - LinkedIn]
3. Then click the `Account` tab and select `Close your Account` 
   [image: LinkedIn-CloseAccount]

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately we are not dealing with humans here !!
Go ahead and "close the account" -- as per numerous blogs.
 However, you need to create a second (accessible) email (XXXX@aol.com etc).
 Change everything in your profile to "XXXX" - except zipcodes and other "flags"
Respond to their so called security email as "approved"
  Go into your profile and make this "XXXX@etc your primary email
Wait 24 hrs and now delete your real email. 
  While it doesn't get rid of your data (for one year) at least you stop
getting their spam !!
  Bottom line -- stay AWAY from ANY social media - if you want to have a (private) life !!